# Pass UTM parameter to URL from Controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, parameter-passing

In my application, I show different design *(in `posts#show`)* to each user based on *weight*.

I basically make different designs for each post and give them *weight* and it randomly shows different design to each user. I basically do A/B testing of these design and track click-rates, views etc.

What I have been trying to fix, is to pass *chosen* design `ID` as a parameter to URL for trackings *(For instance: `www.my-site.com/ab-testing-post?utm_content=2`)*

This is how I select one design to show:

```
designs = @post.designs.pluck(:id, :weight).to_h
@design_distribution = WeightedDistribution.new(designs)
selected_design = @design_distribution.sample
@design = Design.find_by_id(selected_design)
```

I have tested with `redirect_to`, but I get *too many redirects error.*

How am I able to pass `Design ID/ @design.id` as `utm_content` when my post/page is loaded?

PS: When the design has been chosen, I can't do `redirect_to @design` because of advertising restrictions for doing redirects and what I do is to load the designs code in `posts#show` with using `html_safe` & That's the reason I need to be on the same page and pass the UTM instead.

Comment: I'm not sure we know enough but `redirect_to @design` should work.  It should render to `/designs/:id`.  Can we see the logs when you do that?

Comment: @Anthony I can't do `redirect_to @design`, because of advertising restriction. so just load the code design code in `posts#show`